# Need SUMIFS to return multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

The error I'm getting:

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 3.
> Actual: 1.

I think I know why I'm getting this error. As you can see in the formula and table below, there are three months worth of data. This would cause three rows with the first Array. However, the SUMIFS function is only returning one number it seems like. However, I need it to return a row for each month. I suspect 3 rows are expected in the error because there are three months, as returned by the first array. Is my understanding of this error correct?

Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({{unique(text(A1:A,"MMM YY"))},
 {ABS(SUMIFS(C1:C,B1:B,G1,text(A1:A,"MMM YY"), unique(text(A1:A,"MMM YY"))))}})
```

Note: I am using entire columns so the function will still work without adjustment when more data is added.

Data:

| Date | Category | Payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2021 | Food | $5 |
| 02/03/2021 | Food | $5 |
| 02/06/2021 | Fee | $5 |
| 03/03/2021 | Food | $5 |

`G1` is `Food`

Expected output:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 21 | $5 |
| Feb 21 | $5 |
| Mar 21 | $5 |

How can I get SUMIFS to return a new row for each month? Do I need to use a function like OFFSET?

Comment: Unfortunately SUMIFS doesn't allow you to use it in an array formula where the criteria are an array to deliver a separate result for each value of the criteria (unlike Sumif, which does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF` + `ARRAYFORMULA` instead of `SUMIFS`

`=ArrayFormula(unique(if(A2:A<>"",{text(A2:A,"MMM YY"),sumif(text(A2:A,"MMM YY")&B2:B,text(A2:A,"MMM YY")&"Food",C2:C)},)))`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate the payments by month and show the result for each category in a separate column with a `query()` formula that uses a `pivot` clause, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { A1:C, text(A1:A, "yyyy-mm") }, 
    "select Col4, sum(Col3) 
     where Col3 is not null 
     group by Col4 
     pivot Col2", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```

To only show the category specified in cell `G1`, use this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { A1:C, text(A1:A, "yyyy-mm") }, 
    "select Col4, sum(Col3) 
     where Col2 = '" & G1 & "' 
     group by Col4 
     label sum(Col3) '" & G1 & "' ", 
    1 
  ) 
)
```